# Pandas Data Frame manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and trying to write the below code. I can do it using a for loop, iterating over the rows, but I can to see if it is possible to vectorize or without the for loop.

```
Col1 Col2
ABC  A 
ABC1 B
CA   C
PU   C
XYZ  A
```

What I want to do is:
IF Col1 contains only uppercase alphabets - then update Col2 to 'A'
IF Col1 has specific strings "CA" or "PU" - then update Col2 to 'C'
IF Col1 has alphanumeric values - then update Col2 to 'B'

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to be very careful about the overlap of your conditions and what order you prioritize them.  To get what you asked for, I did this using `np.select`

```
cond0 = df.Col1.str.isalpha()
cond1 = df.Col1.str.isupper()
cond2 = df.Col1.isin(['CA', 'PU'])
cond3 = df.Col1.str.isalnum()

df.assign(Col2=np.select([cond2, cond0 & cond1, cond3], ['C', 'A', 'B']))

   Col1 Col2
0   ABC    A
1  ABC1    B
2    CA    C
3    PU    C
4   XYZ    A
```

---

Or use `map`

```
def all_the_conditions(s):
    if s in {'CA', 'PU'}:
        return 'C'
    elif s.isalpha() and s.isupper():
        return 'A'
    elif s.isalnum():
        return 'B'
    else:
        return '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'

df.assign(Col2=df.Col1.map(all_the_conditions))

   Col1 Col2
0   ABC    A
1  ABC1    B
2    CA    C
3    PU    C
4   XYZ    A
```

Comment: Thanks, the first approach worked just fine. Follow up question on using map - should I pass the column name as the parameter 's' in the all_the_conditions function?

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex you can do it

```
df[df["col1"].str.contains(r"\b[A-Z]+\b", case=True)]["col2"] = "A"
df[df["col1"].isin(["CA", "PU"])]["col2"] = "C"
df[df["col1"].str.contains(".*?\d+.*?", regex=True)]["col2"] = "B"
```

Hope this will work

as suggested by @walterTross we can use this as well

```
df[df["col1"].str.contains(r"^[A-Z]+$", case=True)]["col2"] = "A"
df[df["col1"].str.contains("^[A-Z0-9]$", regex=True)]["col2"] = "B"
```

Thanks Walter :)

Comment: `contains("[A-Z]")` doesn't seem to be the same as “contains only uppercase alphabets” (sic)

Comment: @WalterTross Thanks for highlighting

Comment: I think you should use `^` and `$` instead of `\b`. And also the other regex...

Comment: “alphanumeric values” as a regex is probably `"^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"`

Comment: Thanks @WalterTross

Comment: @SurajSareen - Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

c1 = df.Col1.str.isupper()
c2 = df.Col1.isin(['CA','PU'])
c3 = df.Col1.str.contains(r'\d')

df['Col2'] = np.select([c1 & ~(c2 | c3), c2, c3], ['A', 'C', 'B'])

print(df)

   Col1 Col2
0   ABC    A
1  ABC1    B
2    CA    C
3    PU    C
4   XYZ    A
```

Comment: Thank you for your response !